# Converting React Higher Order Component (HOC) to TypeScript Causes Error: "Exported variable has or is using private name"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

Calling for help from TypeScript experts, I'm running into an error while trying to rewrite a React Higher Order Component (HOC) into TS.  I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

> "src/withEnv.tsx(15,14): error TS4025: Exported variable 'withEnv' has or is using private name 'WithEnv'."

My code -

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Context from './context'
import hoistNonReactStatic from 'hoist-non-react-statics'

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component'
}

function defaultEnvToProps(context) {
  return {
    env: context,
  }
}

const withEnv = (mapper) => (Component) => {
  class WithEnv extends React.Component {
    static displayName: string
    render() {
      return (
        <Context.Consumer>
          {(context) => {
            const props = Object.assign(
              {},
              typeof mapper === 'function'
                ? mapper(context)
                : defaultEnvToProps(context),
              this.props
            )
            return <Component {...props} />
          }}
        </Context.Consumer>
      )
    }
  }
  WithEnv.displayName = WithEnv(${getDisplayName(Component)})
  hoistNonReactStatic(WithEnv, Component)
  return WithEnv
}

export default withEnv
```

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you using? Additionally, could you share your `tsconfig.json`? The snippet works (after adding the missing backticks to `withEnv.displayName = ...`) in CodeSandbox' React Typescript template which uses TypeScript 4.1.2.

Comment: There's a lot of info missing here in order to type this properly.  What type is the value of `Context`?  Does a `mapper` always just return an `env` prop, or does it sometimes return other props?

Comment: Here's a start: https://tsplay.dev/4w1z2N exporting leads to issues related to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information that goes into typing this properly.  Some of that info, such as the type of the context value, is missing from your question so I have tried to fill in the blanks.

I can explain the primary error that you are concerned about and tell you how to fix it.

> "src/withEnv.tsx(15,14): error TS4025: Exported variable 'withEnv' has or is using private name 'WithEnv'."

There is [a discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6307) which will tell you more about this issue.  Typescript chokes because it wants to describe the return type of your `withEnv` HOC as the `WithEnv` private class.  But the declarations file won't include this class because it only exists inside your function, so it cannot be used as a return type.  In order to avoid the error you can manually type the return type of `withEnv` as some component which takes a particular set of props.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import hoistNonReactStatic from 'hoist-non-react-statics'

type ContextValue = {} // what is this ??????

declare const Context: React.Context<ContextValue>;

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<any>): string {
  return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component'
}

function defaultEnvToProps(context: ContextValue): { env: ContextValue } {
  return {
    env: context,
  }
}

// define a type for a function that maps your context to props
type Mapper<Return> = (context: ContextValue) => Return;

// generic type `MappedProps` describes the props returned by the mapper
// default value for `MappedProps` type matches `defaultEnvToProps`
export const withEnv = <MappedProps extends {} = { env: ContextValue }>(
  // mapper is an optional function that maps from the context value to the added props
  mapper?: Mapper<MappedProps>
) =>
  // returned function is generic depending on the component props
  <Props extends {}>(
    // takes a component which uses the added props
    Component: ComponentType<MappedProps & Omit<Props, keyof MappedProps>>
    // returns a component which doesn't need those props
  ): ComponentType<Omit<Props, keyof MappedProps>> => {
    // you could just as well use a function component here and use `useContext`
    class WithEnv extends React.Component<Omit<Props, keyof MappedProps>> {
      static displayName: string;
      render() {
        return (
          <Context.Consumer>
            {(context) => {
              const mappedProps = mapper ? mapper(context) : defaultEnvToProps(context);
              return (
                <Component
                  {...this.props}
                  {...mappedProps as MappedProps} // this assertion is only necessary is `mapper` is optional
                />
              )
            }}
          </Context.Consumer>
        )
      }
    }
    WithEnv.displayName = `WithEnv(${getDisplayName(Component)})`;
    hoistNonReactStatic(WithEnv, Component);
    return WithEnv;
  }
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8rKw)